# Closed form of this sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, zeta-functions

$$\sum _{ s=1 }^{ \infty }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ 4s-1 } \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ n+1 } \sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ \left( \left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} \right) \frac { { \left( -1 \right) }^{ k } }{ { \left( k+1 \right) }^{ s-1 } } \right) } \right) } -1 \right) }$$

I am getting it to be equal to $\displaystyle \sum_{s=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{(s-1)\zeta(s)}{4s-1} - 1\right)}$.

But the next sum seems to be diverging. Where am I wrong?

I reached till here by using $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}{{x}^{s-2} {e}^{-(k+1)x} \ dx} = \frac{(s-2)!}{{(k+1)}^{s-1}}$

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^{s-1}} &=& \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s-2}}{(s-2)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k e^{-(k+1)x}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s-2}}{(s-2)!}e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})^n\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^{s-1}}&=&-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{(s-2)!(e^x-1)}\,dx\\&=&(1-s)\,\zeta(s)\end{eqnarray*}$$
and the original series is not converging.

Comment: So, I am right it is diverging. The problem is surely wrong, right?

Comment: @KartikSharma: I believe so.

Comment: What about this -  $$\sum _{ s=1 }^{ \infty }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ 4s-1 } \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ n+1 } \sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ \left( \left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} \right) \frac { { \left( -1 \right) }^{ k } }{ { \left( k+1 \right) }^{ 4s-1 } } \right) } \right) } -1 \right) }$$?

Comment: @KartikSharma: that is a different question that can be tackled with the same approach. At least at first sight, it may lead to a convergent series.

Comment: Yeah, I have used the same approach and got something like $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{sin(x) - sinh(x) \ dx}{{e}^{x} - 1}}$ and that seems to be solvable but is quite tedious. Is there any other method to solve it other than replacing sin and sinh by exponential equivalents?

Comment: @KartikSharma: that is not an integrable function, since the integrand function tends to $-\frac{1}{2}$ as $x\to +\infty$.